# How to record ANY of Android MLKIT detection to a video?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm building app that uses cameraX to display real-time filter on users body, but I am not aware of what would be best way to record/capture video with overlays on it. I've tried screencapturing, but it does not work, I've tried multiple other methods, but no success yet

For code reference, I'm using this sample code - https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXAdvanced

For example, I'd like to make a recording of something like this with all overlays/details on the screen[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a programming way or just a tool to record video manually? If latter, you can try the built-in screen record from Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video

Comment: Hey, more like programming way, I've already tried screen recording, but it does suite the purpose sadly. It takes status bar, asks for forced additional permissions everytime, so really bad UX. Looks like figuring out how to record surfaceview is the only way, but it's hard and I'm having issues figuring it out, would love an example

Comment: Hey @VaclovasRekašiusJr.,
Have you found any solution for it?

Comment: Hey, still looking thru it, couldn't find it yet